# Varnish version 6.3 vcl test fails with custom http header starting with a number

Tags: header, varnish, varnish-vcl

```
Message from VCC-compiler:
Symbol 'req.http' has wrong type (none): 
At: ('/etc/varnish/default.vcl' Line 182 Pos 9) -- (Pos 16)
    set req.http.7hello = "world"; 
--------########-------------------

Symbol was builtin
Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2
VCL compilation failed
```

same code works when using a letter before the number  :

`set req.http.x7hello = "world";`

before submitting a bug a report in github  wanted to check if someone is familiar with this issue ?

Update:

This is working in Varnish previous versions :  tested with  5.2.1 and 6.2.1

Comment: I don't have a specific reference, but many languages do not allow variables to start with a number. My guess is that this is working as the Varnish authors intend.

Comment: This was working in Varnish previous versions. Tested with 5.2.1 and 6.2.2 .  An update intended by Varnish dev?